# paperclip file not uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I can't manage to use paperclip for a file upload.
I'm following this tutorial

http://larsgebhardt.de/parse-xml-with-ruby-on-rails-paperclip-and-nokogiri/

This is what I did :

```
route.rb:

  resources :users do
    resources :rides do
      resources :comments
    end
    resources :challenges do
      get "accept"
      post 'accept'
    end
  end

...

validates :gpx, presence: true

rides.rb:

  require 'nokogiri'

  class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :challenges

      # Tracksegments
      has_many :tracksegments, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :points, :through => :tracksegments

      has_attached_file :gpx

create_rides.rb

  add_attachment :rides, :gpx

rides/new.html.erb

<h1>New Ride</h1>

<%= form_for [@user,@ride] do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :gpx, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div>
      <%= f.file_field :gpx %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div>
  <%= link_to 'Back', user_rides_path %>
</div>
```

Everything renders well but the file is not uploaded. The page is stuck due to the present validation set in the model.rb. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your form tag

```
<%= form_for [@user,@ride], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

and I know paperclip likes this setup for the Database

```
def self.up
  change_table :rides do |t|
    t.attachment :gpx
  end
end

def self.down
  drop_attached_file :rides, :gpx
end
```

And lastly check your Rides Controller and make sure :gpx is an attribute. If youre using Rails4, and have a default configuration, at the bottom of the Rides Controller should be your ride_params and make sure :gpx is permitted.

Comment: :gpx was not permitted in my controller